# how do i create a chart in python to find the relationship between each property type and total price of each property type?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

[Image of preferred graph output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0dAy3.png)i tried to convert my categorial variable (property type) to a numeric one by using count and the total price of each property type to get the correlation. However, I have trouble coming up with a chart to reflect this relationship. Link attached shows the preferred graph output

```
import pandas as pd
total_price_by_type = df.groupby("Type")["Price ($)"].sum()
print(total_price_by_type) 
corr_count_total=num_property_type.corr(total_price_by_type)
print(corr_count_total)

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
total_prices=df.groupby('Type')['Price ($)'].sum()
print(total_prices)
total_prices_sorted.plot(kind='bar',x='Type',y='Price ($)',rot=0)
plt.xlabel('Number of Property Type')
plt.ylabel('Total Price')
plt.title('Correlation between Number of Property Type and Total Price')
plt.show()`
```